# GXT 3 mobile support

Tags: gwt, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, gxt

Support GXT 3 responsitive design out of the box or is there another way to get a good mobile application with GXT running. I know about Sencha Touch but I don't want to develop two standalone apps..

Regards, Markus

Answer (score 0):

2015-01-22 update without mentioning a date, but looks promising: [*sencha.com: Taking a Look at Sencha GXT and GWT*](http://www.sencha.com/blog/taking-a-look-at-sencha-gxt-and-gwt)

---

it seems in **summer 2014** (around now :-)) we should get this natively with **GXT 4.0** from Sencha: http://www.sencha.com/blog/gxt-roadmap-update/

- ***full tablet support (touch gestures, smooth scrolling, drag and drop, and more...)***

But it seems with **touch4j** (http://emitrom.com/touch4j) (***A simple to use Java API for Sencha Touch, Google Maps and Apache Cordova(PhoneGap)***) as mentioned here:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?125865-GXT-to-incorporate-Touch-interface-for-mobile-and-IPad&s=77af04972b2d8e9a218a28f2faf0532b&p=886769&viewfull=1#post886769

it seems already possible now to **leverage GXT/GWT/Sencha Touch coding only Java**

I'll try this out sometime soon.

Comment: another related thread, but still not out yet: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?275726-GXT-Design-logic-for-version-4.0-with-tablets&s=f2817c7e7d82090c9c4e22ff6afe7056&p=1034912&viewfull=1#post1034912

Comment: repo link with latest versions RCs etc.: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sencha.gxt/gxt

Comment: **But!** As I had just to learn: **Firefox** Browsers (more specific **Gecko-engine-based** ones) are **NOT SUPPORTED :-(**. Webkit is so dominating in the mobile world that there seems to be not enough reason to do this currently: 2014/07: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?288823-Form-Submit-Firefox-does-not-work, 2012/07: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?120949-Sencha-Touch-WebKit-and-Firefox/page2&s=ee635f83b1b763e8c456df56535b4617 and wrapping WebKit seems almost impossible: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Platform/Layout/CSS_Compatibility

Comment: the *gwt-touch* Google Code project seems to be a dead child since 2011: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-touch/source/list

Comment: it seems that only a hybrid (at best well code-separated/interfaced) *jQuery mobile*-*GWT*-solution is the only reasonable way to get broad desktop/mobile browser support in a more robust, centralized, enterprise-level development project: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Comment: so **jqm4gwt** seems to be a good candidate to try out as a **best-of-bread solution** for me: https://github.com/jqm4gwt/jqm4gwt (latest version: 1.4.3 (2014/07)) it even **supports** the very good GWT **UIBinder** technology

Comment: ***jqm4gwt* is really fantastic!** The first project implementation went pretty cool where as a 2nd one just based on statically served content based on jQM with docpad also went very smooth! Very nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes with [GWTP](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/) its easy to use [Form Factors](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/advanced/index.html) and create specific versions of your project;

[image]

I would use Form Factors instead of [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) because the table/mobile versions need a different screen approach.
In addition Sencha/IDERA GXT 4.0.X has already some touch-screen support with a [Gesture System and Touch Scroller.](https://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-gxt-4-is-generally-available/)